# How to return a group of rows when one row meets "where" criteria in SQL Anywhere

Tags: where-clause, having, sqlanywhere, where-in

I am somewhat overwhelmed by what I am trying to do, since I have only been using SQL for 3 days now, but I already love the increased functionality over MS query.  The need for the IN function is what drove me to learn about this, and I thank the community for the info here to get me through learning that.

I tried looking thru other questions, but I couldn't find one in which the intent was to group more than two rows, or to group a varying number of rows. This means that count and duplicate are both out as options.

What I am doing is analyzing a table of part number information that spans multiple store locations. The table gives a row to each instance of a part number, so if all 15 stores have some sort of history for a given part number, that part number will have 15 rows in the table.

I am wanting to look at other store's history for parts that meet the criteria of 0 sales history for my location.  The purpose is to see if they can be transferred to another store instead of being returned to the vendor and incurring a restock fee.

Here is a simplified version of the table organized in the way I would want the output to be structured.  I got here by having suspected part numbers and using the list of them as a text string in IN() but I want to go about this the other way and build a list of part numbers from sales data in this table.

```
Branch| Part_No| Description|  Bin Qty|current 12 mo sales|previous 12 mo sales|
------|--------|------------|---------|-------------------|--------------------|
20     CA38385   SUPPORT        2       1                   1
23     CA38385   SUPPORT        1       0                   0
25     CA38385   SUPPORT        0       0                   1

20     DFC10513   Hdw Kit       0       1                   0
23     DFC10513   Hdw Kit       1       0                   0
07     DFC10513   Hdw Kit       0       1                   0

3      D59096     VALVE         0       0                  12
5      D59096     VALVE         0       0                   4
6      D59096     VALVE         4       6                  12
8      D59096     VALVE         0       0                   0
33     D59096     VALVE        11      14                  18
21     D59096     VALVE         4       4                   4
22     D59096     VALVE         0       0                   0
23     D59096     VALVE        10       0                   0
24     D59096     VALVE         0       0                   0
25     D59096     VALVE         0       0                   0
26     D59096     VALVE         2       2                   0

1      TE67401  Repair Kit      1       1                   2
21     TE67401  REPAIR KIT      1       3                   0
22     TE67401  REPAIR KIT      0       1                   0
```

I am branch 23, so the start of the query as I understand it would be

```
Select * from part_information
Group By part_number
Having IN(Branch) 23 and bin qty > 0 and current_12_mo_sales=0 and previous_12_mo_sales = 0
```

Can you point me down the right track?  This table has approx. 200000 rows in it, so I really need to learn how to do this.  I really don't see a better way.

Thank you in advance for your help and or criticism -Cody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working the way I wanted

```
    SELECT pi_Branch, pi_Franchise, pi_Part_No, pi_Description, pi_Bin_Qty,
           pi_Bin, pi_current_12_mo_sales, pi_previous_12_mo_sales, pi_Inventory_Cost, 
           pi_Return_Indicator 
    From Part_Information
             Where pi_Part_No IN (Select pi_Part_No
                                  From Part_Information
                                  Where pi_Branch=23 And 
                                  pi_Bin_Qty>0 And pi_current_12_mo_sales<=0 
                                  And pi_previous_12_mo_sales<=0)
```

I was thinking that this had to be some complex process, but in reality, two simple queries were all that was needed.

I would still be interested in anyone's opinion on a better or more efficient way of handling this.

Thanks Mischa for getting me there!

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from part_information 
where part_number not in (
      select part_number from part_information 
       where branch = 23 and bin_qty > 0  -- etc...
)`

(Apologies for lack of formatting).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that approach, but I see one problem.  I would want to include branch 23's row in the output for any parts that meet those criteria.  This is so I can see other details such as my bin qty, in stock cost, and potentially any other of the almost 200 columns in the full table.  I had simplified the table as much as possible in order to convey my need while still showing the dataset.  If the table truly was as simple as I first posted, with your approach I could just assume all of those values based on my criteria.

Comment: Not sure I understand that fully, but how about adding `or branch = 35 and...` ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to discuss this with me. I really appreciate it.  Let me see if I can concisely word the query that I would like to write.

Comment: The first part of the query is just my stipulations regarding sales or stock or whatnot, but the second part is what is throwing me off.  

After my Where or having statement picks a row that matches my criteria, I would like it to return all rows that contain the same part number (Somewhere between 0 and 14 more rows).

I would want this to continue through to the end of the table, finding all 'Where' matches and pulling in the rest of the rows in the table with the same "part number" text string in the part number column.

Comment: Writing that out gave me an idea.  I will research how to use subqueries, but I think if I write a (inner or sub) query that just picks my one row per part number,  I should be able to use that output in the parent query to return any row with a value 'IN' the output of my subquery.  Does this sound feasible?